# how to execute dmls in a table on a database?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I have 100 DMLS in a temp_table table on oracle database. There are 3 columns in that table seq_no,DMLS,Status. The table looks like below.
seqno,dmls,status

1,insert into......,NULL

2,update table.....,NULL

.

.

100,delete table...,NULL

I would like to read the table row by row based on the seqno and execute the dml in that row on the database. after successful execution the status column in this table should be updated as FINISHED. If the DML fail to execute it should update as FAILED and stop there without processing the next rows. I wrote the below procedure but it didnt do the needful. can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE DML_PROC is

CURSOR dml_cur is SELECT SEQ_NO,DMLS,STATUS FROM DMLS_TBL where STATUS=NULL order by SEQ_NO;

BEGIN
 FOR I IN dml_cur
 LOOP

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'I.DMLS';

 UPDATE DMLS_TBL SET STATUS='SUCCESS'
 WHERE SEQ_NO=I.SEQ_NO;
 END LOOP;

 COMMIT;

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN  NULL;

END DML_PROC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems;

1) It has to be `STATUS IS NULL`
2) `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'I.DMLS'` .. actually is executing the string `'I.DMLS'` itself, not its value.

The changed code could be like below. I added a BEGIN block for every DML to be executed and capture the status.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE DML_PROC is
 CURSOR dml_cur is 
    SELECT SEQ_NO,DMLS,STATUS
    FROM DMLS_TBL
    where STATUS IS NULL
  order by SEQ_NO;
 V_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
 FOR I IN dml_cur
 LOOP
     V_STATUS := 'SUCCESS';
     <<execute_ddl>>
     BEGIN
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE I.DMLS;
     EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN
         V_STATUS := 'FAILURE';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.DMLS ||' Error : ' ||SQLERRM);
     END execute_ddl;

    UPDATE DMLS_TBL SET STATUS = V_STATUS
     WHERE SEQ_NO = I.SEQ_NO;

 END LOOP;

 COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
 NULL;
END DML_PROC;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply sir. I made the changes and it worked. but the statement failed when i ran with the procedure as the table is updated with status= failure. i copied and pasted the same statement from the DMLS_TBL table on to the editor and it executed successfully. i checked for syntax errors in the insert statement but didnt find any. not sure what i am missing.

Comment: The statement has any semicolon at last?

Comment: @Sean Add  `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.DMLS ||' Error : ' ||SQLERRM);` to inner exception block, and that would show why it failed!